# Javascript object become undefined on recordset

Tags: javascript, ms-access

I have an acces database and I would like to import data to javascript.

This is my code:

```
function Flight(){
    this.number;
    this.day;
    this.updateDate;
    this.html;
}

var dbPath = "mypath\\flight_bdd.mdb";
var flights = [];

function executeRequest(request){
    //get datas
    var adoConn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
    var adoCmd = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Command");

    adoConn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + dbPath + "'");
    adoCmd.ActiveConnection = adoConn;

    var adOpenDynamic=2;
    var adLockOptimistic=3;

    var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
    rs.open(request, adoConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic);

    return rs;
}

function loadFlightsFromDatabase(){

    //get datas
    var rs = executeRequest("SELECT * FROM flight_data");

    //empty flight array
    flights = [];

    //create flights
    var i = 0
    while(!rs.eof){
            flights[i] = new Flight();

            //set flight data
            flights[i].number = rs.fields("flight_number"); 

            console.log(flights[i].number);
            rs.MoveNext();
            console.log(flights[i].number);
            i++;
    }

}
```

The first console output returns the flight number and the second one returne undefined.
I think the value of the recordset is updated in my object when I have a move next, is there a way to prevent it ?

Comment: Not a Javascript person, but if you have two console.log(flights[i].number) calls within your While, one after the MoveNext, how do you know the second call won't be when rs is at EOF?  I think this could possibly be giving you the issue.  Even if not, I presume it would be an issue anyway.  Good luck.

Comment: Oops, sorry.  You're not reading from the recordset twice, you're reading from your local array.  Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution,

I I concatenate my recordset

```
flights[i].number = rs.fields("flight_number") + "";
```

it works !!

Answer (score 0):

I think your connection goes out of scope and is getting closed. Try creating a disconnected recordset:

```
var adOpenStatic = 3;    
var adUseClient = 3;
var adLockBatchOptimistic = 4; 

var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient;
rs.open(request, adoConn, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic);
rs.ActiveConnection = null;
adoConn.Close;

return rs;
```

But that said, `rs.MoveNext();` should not affect already assigned property of your object (unless it's a reference type). What type is `.number` - can u show structure of Flight?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I try your code and I have an error on `rs.ActiveConnection = null` the error is `Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.` But I have a value when I print `rs.fields("flight_number");` so this is not a connection problem

Comment: Are u sure you're not incrementing i *before* second console output?